# Undefined behavior in std::unordered_set with custom predicate

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, predicate, unordered-set

I have an `std::unordered_set` that is supposed to store pointers to values stored in an `std::list`. The values are first added to the list, then their pointers are inserted into the set. The set uses a predicate that compares the values the pointers point to instead of the addresses. This produces undefined behavior.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> struct set_hash {
  size_t operator()(const T* p) const noexcept {
    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p);
  }
};
template<typename T> struct set_eq {
  bool operator()(const T* a, const T* b) const noexcept {
    std::cout << "*a["<<*a<<"] == *b["<<*b<<"] "
              << boolalpha << (*a == *b) << std::endl;
    return *a == *b;
  }
};

template<typename T> using set_t =
  std::unordered_set<const T*, set_hash<T>, set_eq<T>>;

int main()
{
  set_t<string> set;
  list<string> list{"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d"};

  for (auto& str : list) {
    set.insert(&str);
    cout << str << ' ';
  }
  cout << endl;

  for (auto p : set) cout << *p << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  string c("c");
  cout << **set.find(&c) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

After running the program multiple times I get three possible outputs:

```
a b a c a d 
d a c a b a 
Segmentation fault

a b a c a d 
d a c a b a 
*a[c] == *b[a] false
Segmentation fault

a b a c a d 
d a c a b a 
*a[c] == *b[c] true
c
```

The output I expect is

```
a b a c a d 
a b c (not necessarily in this order)
c
```

with some lines like `*a[c] == *b[c] true`, depending on how many times the predicate is called.

I do not understand what results in undefined behavior.
I get identical results with gcc4.8.2, gcc4.9.1, and gcc4.9.2.

Comment: Is there a special reason you are using pointers? In C++ there is seldom any need to use pointers any more.

Comment: And the reason you get duplicate entries in the set is because you use pointers as the hash. The pointers you add to the set are all different and so the hash function will return different values for each pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes. I encountered this behavior writing something more complicated, but that's not very relevant to the question.

Comment: The invariant you are breaking is that elements that might compare as equal strings might not have the same has value (since they'll can different pointers).

Comment: What is wrong with using pointers as a hash, if I know that nothing will be removed from the list. Aren't lists stable?

Comment: The list contains six different string objects, all with different locations in memory, i.e. six different pointers. If you want the behavior to work a little better, reuse `std::hash` on `*p`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ah, yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the hash function hashes the pointers while the comparison function compares the values pointed at by the pointers.  So if you have two different list elements with the same value, the hash function will give different hashes (from the pointers), while the comparison function will compare equal.

The hash function needs to be consistent -- it needs to hash the values instead of the pointers.